# Linearizing a system of differential equations in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align*}
\dot{r}&=-r^3\cos^4(\theta)\\
\dot{\theta}&=1+r^2\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta).
\end{align*}

I need to show that the fixed point of the system in cartesian coordinates $(0,0)$ is a stable spiral in polar coordinates. I don't really know what to do from here, but I have the Jacobian

\begin{align*}
Df(r,\theta)&=\begin{pmatrix}
-3r^2\cos^4(\theta) & 4r^3\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta)\\
2r\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta) & r^2[-3\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^4(\theta)]
\end{pmatrix}.\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin is an equilibrium point. Let us focus around this equilibrium point.

Since your $\frac {dr}{dt} <0$,  your $r$ is decreasing with time and since your $ \frac {d\theta}{dt} \approx 1 $  you have a rotation around the equilibrium point.

Thus the trajectories are spiraling in around the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so caught up in the quantitative analysis that I neglected this simplistic breakdown.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.

Comment: How do you handle the eventuality $\theta = \pi /2, 3\pi/2$, where the assertion $\dot r < 0$ is false?

Comment: Since the $ \dot r \le  0$ and $\dot \theta =1$ the above argument is still fine.